# new-style ("inline") macros require scala.meta

Tags: scala, scala-macro-paradise, scalameta

I just updated to scala meta 2.0.0-M1 and with the latest scala 2.12.3 and now macros no longer compile. The only change i made was to change the meta version from 1.8.0 to 2.0.0-M1.

ERROR: new-style ("inline") macros require scala.meta

Does anybody know if there is a quick work around for this?

I was hoping to start playing with some of the semantic improvements.

Answer (score 4):

scalameta/paradise currently supports scalameta 1.8.0 only, not 2.0.0-M1. The new improvements in the semantic api are not accessible for macro annotations.

One good place to play around with the semantic improvements is to implement custom scalafix rewrites https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/#scalacenter/scalafix.g8