# Scala Meta: Confused about the versions

Tags: scala, scalameta

In the [tutorial](https://github.com/scalameta/tutorial/blob/master/project/Dependencies.scala) you find 2 versions for Scala-Meta.

```
lazy val MetaVersion = "3.7.2"
lazy val MetaVersion1 = "1.8.0"
```

I am a bit confused as they seem to refer the same project:

```
lazy val scalameta1 = "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % MetaVersion1
lazy val scalameta = "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % MetaVersion
```

Can somebody point out the difference, and when you use which one of these?

The **[Tutorial](http://scalameta.org/tutorial/#AWhirlwindTourofScalameta)** only mentions `"3.7.2"`, but with that I got the exception

`ERROR: new-style ("inline") macros require scala.meta`

explained here: [new-style-inline-macros-require-scala-meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470048/new-style-inline-macros-require-scala-meta?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.7.2 is the current version of scalameta (actually already 3.7.4).

1.8.0 is the last version of scalameta that worked with scalameta macro annotations through scalameta paradise compiler plugin ([1](https://web.archive.org/web/20171214080427/https://scalameta.org/paradise) [2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalameta/paradise) [3](https://github.com/scalameta/paradise)).

So if you need the latest version of scalameta you use 3.7.4. If you need scalameta macros you use 1.8.0.